# Vega Chloropleth Map Visualisation

Tags: maps, tooltip, visualization, vega-lite, vega

For some reason vega is reading my data as 0 when the numbers range from 1-234.
I am attempting to show a visualisation of a chloropleth map of crypto-ownership by country.
The countries have been ranked 1-234 and that is meant to show on the tooltip however, this is being shown as 0 on the tooltip. How do I fix this.

Here is my code:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "title":{
    "text": "Crypto Ownership Worldwide",
    "subtitle": "Source: FILL",
    "anchor": "start"
  },
  "width":500,
  "height":400,
  "data": {
    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tomiwav/tomiwav.github.io/main/custom.geo%20(3).json",
    "format":{"property": "features"}
  },
  "projection":{"type": "mercator"},

  "transform": [
  {
    "lookup":"properties.name",
    "from":{
      "key": "Country",
      "fields": ["Rank"],
      "data":{
        "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tomiwav/tomiwav.github.io/main/datarank.csv",
        "format":{"type":"csv"}
      }
    
    }
  }
],

  "mark":{
    "type": "geoshape",
    "fill":"lightgray",
    "stroke":"black",
    "strokeWidth":0.5
  },

  "encoding": {
    "color": {
      "field": "Rank",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "scale": {
        "domain":[234,1],
        "scheme": "oranges"
      }
    },
    "tooltip":[
      {"field":"properties.name", "title":"Country"},
      {"field":"Rank","type":"quantitative","title":"Number of Crypto Owners","format":".2f"}
    ]
  },
     "config": {"mark": {"invalid": null}
}

}
```

Comment: Can this be marked as solved?

Answer (score 0):

Your lookup was failing. You need a lower case "c" on country.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "title": {
    "text": "Crypto Ownership Worldwide",
    "subtitle": "Source: FILL",
    "anchor": "start"
  },
  "width": 500,
  "height": 400,
  "data": {
    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tomiwav/tomiwav.github.io/main/custom.geo%20(3).json",
    "format": {"property": "features"}
  },
  "projection": {"type": "mercator"},
  "transform": [
    {
      "lookup": "properties.name",
      
      "from": {
        
        "key": "country",
        "fields": ["Rank"],
        "data": {
          "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tomiwav/tomiwav.github.io/main/datarank.csv",
          "format": {"type": "csv"}
        }      }
    }
  ],
  "mark": {
    "type": "geoshape",
    "fill": "lightgray",
    "stroke": "black",
    "strokeWidth": 0.5
  },
  "encoding": {
    "color": {
      "field": "Rank",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "scale": {"domain": [234, 1], "scheme": "oranges"}
    },
    "tooltip": [
      {"field": "properties.name", "title": "Country"},
      {
        "field": "Rank",
        "type": "quantitative",
        "title": "Number of Crypto Owners",
        "format": ".2f"
      }
    ]
  },
  "config": {"mark": {"invalid": null}}
}
```